# Collapse a 3D model to 2d with Shader?

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I'm trying to recreate an effect of 3D sprites similar to Ocotpath Traveler (2d sprite similar to billboards/imposters in 3D space, showing 8 sides of the character based on where they're facing), however, I don't want to create thousands of high quality sprites by hand, but instead just use 3D models and render them into ok-quality 2D sprites (including Normal Map, Metallic/Smoothness, Ambient Occlusion).

**At runtime.**

[image: Image showing effect]
[Model used in example](https://old.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/jtg3ru/i_made_6_animated_rpg_characters_you_can_use_for/)

Desired effect, 2D sprite on the left, 3D model on the right. Sprite took manually whole day for the 4 textures in Blender, hope shader can do that in less than 1ms. Dark AO effect is to simulate cell-shading. The gold pixels on the chest are Metallic in my sprite. The original model is albedo textured only.

Being able to plug 3D models together into characters, posing them, and just rendering a sprite  would be quite a boon for the model/animation pipeline and variation in the resulting characters. I could create new characters at the press of a button. A new hat would be just another model, instead of hundreds of new sprite sheets for every animation and view.

One brute force approach would be using RenderTargets (in Unity) to render the models every once in a while, but I don't think this would work well with specular lighting and such that I want from the resulting sprite.

I know you can do lots of crazy things with shaders, and I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve this effect. Projecting the vertex into 2D is easy (replacing them with 4 hard coded vertex even more), but before that I would have to take their Normal values (plus potential normal map) and get them into a texture, and that's where I simply have no idea how to even start.

I'm also open for other approaches to this concept. Confirming that this is not possible with shaders would also be a boon.

Comment: If you haven't stumbled onto these yet, Dead Cells' art pipeline might be of interest to you: https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/313026/Art_Design_Deep_Dive_Using_a_3D_pipeline_for_2D_animation_in_Dead_Cells.php https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNDRre6q98g

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I already did in the example image, however I really would like to not bake any textures before hand, even when it impacts performance.
Baking textures is plan C at this point.

Comment: Is this not just a matter of rendering your model in multiple different poses/angles to a sprite atlas RenderTexture? Or a sequence of such atlasses, if you want one for albedo, one for normals, etc - kind of like rendering a G-Buffer for deferred rendering.

Comment: You mean rendering the atlas at runtime? This is one option I'd consider plan B. The issue would be that I either define a set of animations when I need a new character and render them all at once at spawn (potential delay, or spike when I spawn many), or I only render the one sprite I need at the moment and keep track of what I have and don't have.
That said, I couldn't find a good reference to render, for example, a normal map from a 3D model, and then plug it into a material.

Comment: It is unlikely you'd get a shader to reproduce exactly what you want. Looking at the right shoulder in particular, there is a large gap in information between the two images.

Comment: I don't see what you mean with the shoulder, but that's pretty much why I'm asking. I'm not familiar enough with shaders to know their limits. Thanks.

Comment: I've [seen something like that in Saints Row IV](https://youtu.be/GVbDXdvV_sE?t=337).  You can tell it's not hand-pixeled but generated at runtime, because it applies all the character customization options to the player-character. And SRIV has far too many of those to hand-pixel them all just for that short sequence.